# People Pane in Outlook 2010 doesn't show any emails, or does

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

People Pane in Outlook 2010 either does not show any emails, or only shows some emails for other folders. I've tried re-indexing and recreating the profile, to no avail.

I really like the new People Pane in Outlook 2010. Not for the "Social" features, but for finding related emails and attachments. But it just does not work. It is totally broken.

Do you know some trick to make it work?

Using 32-bit Outlook local version, without Exchange.

Comment: If there's nothing left to do, you could always try repairing the installation...

Comment: I can confirm this problem with Exchange and Windows 7.  I am not looking for any of the Social issues, just the features similar to what Xobni offers for email, attachments, meetings.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to a similar problem I was having with an Exchange server.

Open a registry editor (Start -> Run; then type regedit.exe)

Navigate to the following:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\SocialConnector
```

Create a new String value, if one does not exist for:

```
RunOSC = 1
```

If you need to create a new String value, right click in the registry editor right-hand pane,  select New, then select String Value.  After creating a String Value for RunOSC, double click it and give it a value of 1.

After restarting Outlook, the People Pane now displays emails, meetings and attachments.

Answer (score 0):

From this thread - [Outlook Social Connector in Outlook 2010 stays blank](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlook/thread/1cc044c2-4dd4-4b9f-8244-80ef1116680a):

> To get the best out of the PeoplePane
>   with Exchange is to ENABLE Cached mode
>   in your account settings!
>
> It will create a local offline copy,
>   which is basicly a new index, this
>   makes the PeoplePane work eventually.
>
> You do not really need the Social
>   Network at first..

Some more advice from [Outlook Social Connector a worthwhile add-on](http://www.networkworld.com/reviews/2010/021910-outlook-social-connector-a-worthwhile.html)

> Be aware that, in order to run the
>   latest version of the Outlook Social
>   Connector and the associated LinkedIn
>   connector, you first have to uninstall
>   the version of the Outlook Social
>   Connector that came with the beta of
>   Office 2010.
>
> The Outlook Social Connector also
>   lacks several useful features offered
>   by the free [Xobni](http://www.xobni.com/) Outlook add-in,
>   which also connects Outlook to social
>   networks. Xobni pulls more information
>   into Outlook than does the Outlook
>   Social Connector's Reading Pane, such
>   as the contact's title and location.
>   It also lets you preview entire
>   messages, not just subject lines, and
>   does a better job of displaying
>   threads in conversations. Xobni also
>   connects to multiple social networks,
>   including LinkedIn, Facebook and
>   Twitter. And Xobni allows two-way
>   communications -- you can post a
>   Twitter update within Outlook, for
>   example.
>
> In case you want to use both the
>   Outlook Social Connector and Xobni at
>   the same time, you can; I use them
>   both and have found no conflicts
>   between them.

Comment: I'm not using Exchange (as stated in answer). Don't know what this Xobni comment have to with the answer.

Comment: @Eduardo Molteni: Xobni is an alternative that works and works well, while the People pane gets many complaints. I also hope that you have not previously installed the Office beta.

Comment: Yes, I know Xobni and wished I can get ride of it with the new People Pane. I have not installed the beta.